# how to access more than one text box which is in onchange Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sel(){
                var y=document.getElementById("demo1").value;
                document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML=y;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <?php 
        for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
    ?> 
    <input type="text" name="doi" required="" placeholder="current inspect date" id="demo1" onchange="sel()" required>
    <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('demo1','ddmmmyyyy','arrow')"><img src="cal.gif" alt="failed to load img"></a>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <p id="cal"></p>
</html>
```

([datetimepicker_css.js is my calender file used to select date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3oZ3.png)); two textbox id=demo[after select of calender it print correct when i select other calender first text is affected. I need to access two text value after selecting each calender.

[image]

Comment: you are not clear with your question ... how much you have succesfully done ..and what more you want ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery selector here and update values on change event of every input box provided that you should use some common selector like name, class etc.

See below code, where i have used class="doi" for multiple inputs and bind change event handler to it. iterate inputs to get values for on change event of any input box.

**Note**:- It is not recommended to use same id for multiple elements. This may cause to issue in scripts. Please remove `id="demo1"`from input as this will create multiple inputs with same id.

```
<input type="text" name="doi" required="" 
       placeholder="current inspect date" 
       onchange="sel()" required class="doi">
<input type="text" name="doi" required="" 
       placeholder="current inspect date" 
       onchange="sel()" required class="doi">
```

jQuery : register handler

```
$(function(){
  $('input.doi').change(function(){
    $("#cal").empty(); // clear cal para
    //set value of each input to cal
    $('input.doi').each(function(){
        $("#cal").append($(this).val() + " , ");
    });      
  });
});
```

Comment: bro i didnt get you!!

Comment: here I have attach click event handler for all input having `class="doi"`. When you change input, this function gets called inside which I am iterating all inputs with `class="doi"` and appending its values to `cal`. This way you are adding all input values to `cal` everytime you change input.

Answer (score 1):

*when i select other calender first text is affected.*

Again same issue of ***same IDs applied on multiple elements*** in a single page.

As per valid markup you should always put unique id on your elements and that should be **unique**.
When you don't do it what happens in the element lookup in your case, the browser goes to find the element with the given id with:

```
var y=document.getElementById("demo1").value;
```

so when browser gets the first one it returns it's value as code suggests but when you try to get the second one it still returns the first one.

#### Why?

With given ids browser stops the element lookup in the document when it finds first element with the supplied id.

### What can be done?

You have two options either you give unique IDs or use a common classname like:

with IDs:

```
<?php 
    for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
?> 
    <input type="text" name="doi" required="" placeholder="current inspect date" 
           id="demo<?php echo $i+1?>" onchange="sel()" required>
    <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('demo<?php echo $i+1?>','ddmmmyyyy','arrow')">
        <img src="cal.gif" alt="failed to load img">
    </a>

<?php
}
?>
```

This `id="demo<?php echo $i+1?>"` would produce unique IDs.

With common class name:

```
<?php 
    for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
?> 
    <input type="text" name="doi" required="" 
           placeholder="current inspect date" class="demo" onchange="sel(this)" required>
    <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('demo','ddmmmyyyy','arrow')">
        <img src="cal.gif" alt="failed to load img">
    </a>

<?php
}
?>
```

You can see a change here `onchange="sel(this)"` you can pass `this` element in the function and change the function to accept arguments like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function sel(el){ // <-----el is the element 'this'
      var y=el.value;
      document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML=y;
   }
</script>
```